How are SwiftUI .preference values passed up in the hierarchy
Working with .preference / .onPreferenceChange in SwiftUI I would sometimes wonder "why is this value not passed up". I reproduced my feeling-puzzled with this example:
struct ExamplePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: Int = 0

    static func reduce(value: inout Int, nextValue: () -> Int) {
        let nextValue = nextValue()
        print("»reduce»", value, "<-", nextValue)
        value = nextValue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .preference(
                    key: ExamplePreferenceKey.self,
                    value: 123
                )
                .onPreferenceChange(ExamplePreferenceKey.self) { size in
                    print("»", size)
                }
            
            VStack {
                // if true {    // <-- Uncomment the if statement
                    Text("yo")
                // }
            }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(ExamplePreferenceKey.self) { size in
            print("»»", size)
        }
    }
}

This works and you'll see the preference changing on the element and also on the outer ZStack:
»» 123
» 123

Now uncomment the if-statement and the outer ZStack will not have the value anymore and you can see that another preference-default-value will overwrite the existing value (tested on iOS 17.4):
»reduce» 123 <- 0
»» 0
» 123

At first, the lesson here is to know that this can happen and you need to implement the reduce function accordingly, even if just one '.preference' modifier will be present.
But still: Why does this happen? Why does including the if-statement in a sibling View cause the appearance of another 'default' preference value?
I mean, if it would be the case that any sibling to a node with an explicit preference value would bring in the default, that would make sense. But that this default value is not present when it’s just a sibling, but if you add an ‘if true’ to that sibling view, it now brings in the default value for the preference, is incomprehensible to me. What's going on here?

I think this is pretty similar to this question. I don't think the "why" here is particularly interesting. It probably has to do some internal implementation detail that is close-source. As you have learned in your "lesson", SwiftUI "reserves the right" to not call reduce wherever it likes. This is spelled out in the documentation as "reduce(value: &x, nextValue: {defaultValue}) shouldn't change the meaning of x".
